# Explicitly calculate convolution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, convolution, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I want to calculate a convolution in Python by explicitly evaluating the integral

[image: convolution]

and comparing the result with what I get from [`fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html). The integral would be calculated using [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import symbols

def f(x,a,b):
    return np.exp(-(x-a)**2/b)

def g(x,a,b):
    return np.exp(-(x-np.pi*a)**2/(2.9*b))

x = symbols('x')

a = 1.2
b = 4.7

t = np.linspace(-100,100,int(1e4))
dt = t[1] - t[0]

h1 = fftconvolve(f(t,a,b),g(t,a,b),mode='same')*dt

h2,_ = quad(f(t,a,b)*g(x-t,a,b),-np.inf,np.inf,epsabs=0,epsrel=1e-6,args=(a,b))
x = np.linspace(-100,100,int(1e4))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,h1,label='fftconvolve')
plt.plot(x,h2,label='brute force')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'exp'` which refers to the line `h2,_ = quad(...` when it is called by `quad`.

What does this error mean and is this an appropriate way to use `quad` to evaluate the integral?

Comment: `quad` expects a function, you pass a numpy array; also be careful with `x` which is one time treated as a symbol and later as a numpy array.

Comment: Best convert your integral into the form `exp(-x^2) * h(x)` by variable transformation and then use Gauss-Hermite quadrature (e.g., via [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy#1d-space-with-weight-function-exp-r2)).

Comment: If you just want to evaluate the convolution then the convolution of two gaussians is another gaussian. You can figure out the constants involved from the fact that if X is a gaussian mean m and sd s, while y is a gaussian mean n sd t than X+Y (whose density function is a gaussian) has mean m+n and sd sqrt(s*s + t*t)

Comment: @dmuir, yes I know, but this is just a MWE. I want to see if it's possible to do convolution for two arbitrary functions `f` and `g` by explicitly evaluating the integral. I'm trying to solve something more complicated than Gaussians, so the example in my post seemed like a good place to start.